# Use axios in Vue Router Navigation Guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I can't use my Vue.prototype.$http  because I don't know how to make it available in my routes file.

*axios.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

// noinspection JSIncompatibleTypesComparison
const isDevelopmentMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// base URL for backend access
const backendUrl = (isDevelopmentMode)
  ? 'http://localhost:8081/'
  : '/backend/';

// register axios as HTTP client
Vue.prototype.$http = axios.create({
  baseURL: backendUrl,
  withCredentials: isDevelopmentMode,
});
```

*index.js* // Vue Router

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import '@/plugins/axios';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

function getSession() {
  const session = this.$http.get('session/info')
    .then((response) => response.data);
  return session;
}
```

Comment: could you should your guard function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.$http` will not work because the `this` pointer in routes.js is different from the `this` pointer in a view component.  Try this in routes.js

`console.log(this)`

And then try the same thing in a Vue component like App.vue.  You'll see the this in the routes.js refers to the router and not the Vue.prototype.

I would suggest modifying your axios.js like this, adding an instance variable and exporting it.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

// noinspection JSIncompatibleTypesComparison
const isDevelopmentMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// base URL for backend access
const backendUrl = (isDevelopmentMode)
  ? 'http://localhost:8081/'
  : '/backend/';

// register axios as HTTP client
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: backendUrl,
  withCredentials: isDevelopmentMode,
});
Vue.prototype.$http = instance;

export default instance // we need to export this
```

then import the instance variable into routes.js (it will be the same one)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import instance from '@/plugins/axios'; // this may be a different path?

Vue.use(VueRouter);

function getSession() {
  const session = instance.get('session/info') // use instance here
    .then((response) => response.data);
  return session;
}
```

Comment: Actually I just used Vue.$http.prototype directly instead of putting it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Import *axios.js* in *router.js*. For this propose do follow steps:

1. export axios object.

*axios.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';

let ax= axios.create({
  baseURL: backendUrl,
  withCredentials: isDevelopmentMode,
});
Vue.prototype.$http = ax;
export default ax;
```

2. Import *axios.js* in *router.js*.

*router.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from "./axios.js"

Vue.use(VueRouter);

function getSession() {
  const session = axios.get('session/info')
    .then((response) => response.data);
  return session;
}
```